# UE4.27.1 Unsupported Google Play Billing Version

Tags: android, unreal-engine4

I have a problem with packaging Unreal project for android and publishing on Google Play Store.
When uploading it shows an error:
We've detected this app uses an unsupported version Play billing. Please upgrade to Billing Library version 3 or newer to publish this app.

I have project configured for Google Play Billing. And in file in engine/plugins/Online the version is set to 3.0.0. I also tried different versions but with no success. Every answer i found was pointing to this file and at this point nothing seems to work.

If anybody faced a similiar issue and knows the answer i would be extremly thankful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Library to change to fix Google app publish error; Billing Library version 3 in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69131336/library-to-change-to-fix-google-app-publish-error-billing-library-version-3-in)

Answer (score 0):

Download this plugin, add it to your project, and enable it in it's settings under Plugins in Project Settings. You don't have to use it or do anything with it. It just includes the library. Can confirm this will pass the Google Play store check.

https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/android-play-billing